# Scrape chained selects with updated data using CasperJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, html-select, casperjs

There are 2 selects with IDs. The 2nd select box data is linked based on what you select on the first select box. In other words, if you select "BMW" in the second select box should appear 316,318,320 ... you got the point.

The first select has listener

```
('#brand').change(function(){
    call ajax and fill the data for the second select box
}
```

What I want to do at the end is to get all the options for models, for all the brands :-)

What I got so far is:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    loadImages:false,
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'debug',
    clientScripts: ["includes/jquery.min.js"]
});

casper.userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36');

casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
    this.echo('remote message caught: ' + msg);
});

casper.on( 'page.error', function (msg, trace) {
    this.echo( 'Error: ' + msg, 'ERROR' );
});

casper.start('http://www.mywebsite.kitchen/');

casper.then(function(){
    this.evaluate(function(valueOptionSelect){
        $('#brand').val(6).trigger('change');
    },optionFirstSelect);

    this.waitFor(function check() {
        return this.evaluate(function(casper) {
            var len = $('#model1 option').length;
            console.log('length of options is ->', len);
            return $('#model1 option').length > 1;
        });
    }, function then() {

       //well i still haven't reach that point

    }, function timeOut(){
        casper.echo(arguments)
    });
});

casper.run(function() {
    //finish execution script
    this.exit();
});
```

now what I get for console log is:

//EDIT - the length is 1 not 0

> length of options is 1

When I execute `$('#brand').val(6).trigger('change'); $('#model1 option').length` in my browser console I get correct results.

Comment: You probably mean `$('#model1 option').length > 0;` in the `check` function. How many `length of options is 0` messages do you get? You should add `this.echo` inside of `waitFor` then callback and timeout callback so you can distinguish them both. Other than that, it looks right.

Comment: there is a default( empty ) option inside model select, that's why i need more then 1.
I see this message "length of options is 0" ~30-50 times. I did tried copule of tried with setTimeout(function(){}) but it didnt change anything. Can you give me some simple example of what you mean by set some timeout.
Thanks

Comment: `setTimeout` shouldn't be used with casperjs, because you'll loose the control flow. You can add `resource.error`, `resource.received`  and `resource.requested` to see if the request completes. Maybe run casperjs with `--web-security=false` command line flag.

Comment: ok so as far as i understood I added:

`casper.on( 'resource.error', function (msg, trace) {
    this.echo( 'THE IS A RESORCE ERROR: ' + msg, 'ERROR' );
});

casper.on( 'resource.received', function (msg, trace) {
    this.echo( 'A Resource has been recieved');
});

casper.on( 'resource.requested', function (msg, trace) {
    this.echo( 'A Resource has been requested');
});`

then i runnded casperjs server.js --web-security=false

what i get is 30-40 of 
A Resource has been requested
A Resource has been requested
A Resource has been recieved
A Resource has been requested